# Is that possible to be aware that Hotjar is now loaded in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hotjar

I want to get userId from Hotjar but I need to make sure Hotjar is loaded. How can I dependent a function to `Hotjar loaded` something like using `.then()` to wait for promise.

```
<Hotjar Code>
.
.
.
<End of Hotjar Code>

let x = hj.globals.get('userId').split('-').shift()
```

Now I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: Hey, did you had a chance to try out the `window` solution? Is it working for you or do you still need an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Referencing another SO question which is close to your question: [Capturing Hotjar User ID in Google Tag Manager & Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644792/capturing-hotjar-user-id-in-google-tag-manager-google-analytics)

Anyway you could check if this property exists and if it's a function. At least this is how I solved it.

One thing might be that you need to wait for the DOM to be available:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    hj.globals.get('userId').split('-').shift()
};
```

Another thing might be that you need to check if the script was loaded at all.

```
if (window.hj && typeof (window.hj) === "function") {
    hj.globals.get('userId').split('-').shift()
}
```

With both in mind I would perhaps suggest the following code to be very save about it.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    if (window.hj && typeof (window.hj) === "function") {
        hj.globals.get('userId').split('-').shift()
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This is not what I'm looking for. I can check that with this condition `if (hj.globals)` . I want to use something like `.then()` to make sure first part was added and then this part happen.

Comment: Thank you for updating code. I will check it and let you know the result.

Comment: It's a pleasure! I'm trying to understand where you come from and where want to go. I assumed `<Hotjar Code>` is the hotjar-script which you got directly from hotjar. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The script that is gotten from hotjar.

Comment: @MohammadTaherian did the document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded') helped? I've also added another question on SO which seems very close to your question.